# Task.Run apparently locks UI when nested too deep

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a WPF application that needs to parse a bunch of large XML files (around 40MB) containing products and save information about all products that are actually books. For progress reporting, I have a datagrid that displays the filename, status ("waiting", "parsing", "completed", that sort of thing), number of products found, number of parsed products, and number of books found, like this:

```
        <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OnixFiles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bestand" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding FileName}" SortMemberPath="FileName" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aantal producten" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NumTotalProducts}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Verwerkte producten" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NumParsedProducts}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aantal geschikte boeken" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NumSuitableBooks}" />                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

When I hit the "Parse" button, I want to iterate through the list of filenames and parse each file, reporting the amount of products, parsed products and found books along the way. Obviously I want my UI to remain responsive so I want to do the parsing on a different thread using Task.Run().

When the user hits a button labeled "Parse", the application needs to start parsing the files. If I call TaskRun right in the button command's command_executed method everything works fine:

```
    private async void ParseFilesCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var f in OnixFiles)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => f.Parse());
        }
    }

    // In the OnixFileViewModel
    public void Parse()
    {
        var progressIndicator = new Progress<ParsingProgress>(ReportProgress);
        var books = Parser.ParseFile(this.fileName, progressIndicator);
    }

    private void ReportProgress(ParsingProgress progress)
    {
        // These are properties that notify the ui of changes
        NumTotalProducts = progress.NumTotalProducs;
        NumParsedProducts = progress.NumParsedProducts;
        NumSuitableBooks = progress.NumSuitableBooks;
    }

    // In the class Parser
public static IEnumerable<Book> ParseFile(string filePath, IProgress<ParsingProgress> progress)
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        var root = XElement.Load(filePath);
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        XNamespace defaultNamespace = "http://www.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference";

        var products = (from p in XElement.Load(filePath).Elements(defaultNamespace + "Product")
                        select p).ToList();

        var parsingProgress = new ParsingProgress()
        {
            NumParsedProducts = 0,
            NumSuitableBooks = 0,
            NumTotalProducs = products.Count
        };

        progress.Report(parsingProgress);

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            // Complex XML parsing goes here
            parsingProgress.NumParsedProducts++;

            if (...) // If parsed product is actual book
            {  
                parsingProgress.NumSuitableBooks++;                 
            }

            progress.Report(parsingProgress);
        }

        return books;
    }
```

It all executes super-fast, the ui gets updated quickly and remains responsive. However, if I move the call to Task.Run() into the ParseFile method, like so:

```
    private async void ParseFilesCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var f in OnixFiles)
        {
            await f.ParseAsync();
        }
    }

    // In the OnixFileViewModel
    public async Task ParseAsync()
    {
        var progressIndicator = new Progress<ParsingProgress>(ReportProgress);
        var books = await Parser.ParseFileAsync(this.fileName, progressIndicator);
    }

    private void ReportProgress(ParsingProgress progress)
    {
        // These are properties that notify the ui of changes
        NumTotalProducts = progress.NumTotalProducs;
        NumParsedProducts = progress.NumParsedProducts;
        NumSuitableBooks = progress.NumSuitableBooks;
    }

    // In the class Parser
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> ParseFileAsync(string filePath, IProgress<ParsingProgress> progress)
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

        var root = XElement.Load(filePath);
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        XNamespace defaultNamespace = "http://www.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference";

        var products = (from p in XElement.Load(filePath).Elements(defaultNamespace + "Product")
                        select p).ToList();

        var parsingProgress = new ParsingProgress()
        {
            NumParsedProducts = 0,
            NumSuitableBooks = 0,
            NumTotalProducs = products.Count
        };

        progress.Report(parsingProgress);

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            // Complex XML parsing goes here
            parsingProgress.NumParsedProducts++;

            if (...) // If parsed product is actual book
            {  
                parsingProgress.NumSuitableBooks++;                 
            }

            progress.Report(parsingProgress);
        }
        });

        return books;
    }
```

The UI locks up, doesn't update until after a file has finished parsing, and everything appears much slower.

What am I missing? Why does it work as expected if you call Task.Run() in the command_executed handler, but not if you call it in an async method called by that method?

**Edit:** as requested by Shaamaan, here's a simpler sample of what I'm doing (using simply thread.sleep to simulate workload) but frustratingly, the sample works like I had originally expected it to, failing to highlight the problem I'm having. Still, adding it for completeness:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ThreadingSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Height="250"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Value}" />                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Click="RightButton_Click">Right</Button>
        <Button Click="WrongButton_Click">Wrong</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ThreadingSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                Things.Add(new Thing(i));
            }
        }

        private async void RightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var t in Things)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => t.Parse());
            }
        }

        private async void WrongButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var t in Things)
            {
                await t.ParseAsync();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Thing.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadingSample
{
    public class Thing : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private int _value;

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        public Thing(int number)
        {
            Name = "Thing nr. " + number;
            Value = 0;
        }

        public void Parse()
        {
            var progressReporter = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
            HeavyParseMethod(progressReporter);
        }

        public async Task ParseAsync()
        {
            var progressReporter = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
            await HeavyParseMethodAsync(progressReporter);
        }

        private void HeavyParseMethod(IProgress<int> progressReporter)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                progressReporter.Report(i);
            }
        }

        private async Task HeavyParseMethodAsync(IProgress<int> progressReporter)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        progressReporter.Report(i);
                    }
                });
        }

        private void ReportProgress(int progressValue)
        {
            this.Value = progressValue;
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The only difference between this sample and my real-life code, that I can tell, is that my real-life code parses a bunch of 40mb xml files using LINQ to XML whereas this sample just calls Thread.Sleep().

**Edit 2:** I've found a horrifying workaround. If I use the second method and call Thread.Sleep(1) after each product is parsed and before calling IProgress.Report(), everything works fine. I can see the "NumParsedProducts" counter increase and everything. This is a terrible hack though. What could it mean?

Comment: I know it's possibly a silly question: can you reproduce your problem using a simpler example? Using `Threading.Sleep` to imitate work-load, for instance? I'm having trouble getting the same effect as you described, albeit I'm creating just a very very basic app for testing...

Comment: The only difference I can see is that in the original code `ReportProgress()` is executed on a background thread, while in the modified code it's executed on the UI thread. How does the call stack of the UI thread look like if you pause the debugger while the UI is locked up?

Comment: I've tried to create a simpler example, but frustratingly both methods are equally responsive in that. Which, obviously, is what I expected in the first place, but that doesn't shed any light on why it's not working in my real-world application. I'll update the question with my simpler sample, though.

Comment: @svick if I pause the debugger while the UI is locked up, I just see [External code] on the call stack.
Weirdly, the UI isn't frozen for most of the operation until half a second or so before the entire file is parsed and the ui gets updated with the totals.

Comment: Edited with info about a weird and terrifying workaround.

Comment: This is probably a firehose problem.  You are generating so many UI updates that the UI thread is completely bogged down trying to keep up.  Generate updates at a rate fit for a human eye.  Once every 50 msec is plenty good enough.

Comment: @HansPassant But why doesn't the first method generate that many UI updates then?

Comment: I don't know, no way I can debug that code.  Finding out that slowing down the worker thread by calling Sleep() is a strong hint that this is a firehose problem.  It lowers the rate at which you pummel the UI thread.  Not what you want to do, sleeping a worker thread is a waste.  Just report progress less often.

Comment: @HansPassant Updated the code to only report progress every 50ms, and now it's indeed performing like it's supposed to, no matter which method I use. Just to be sure I took some average measurements (basedon 4 samples)of how long it takes to parse three files. The first method took 6081.84785ms, the (old) second method took 7864,949875ms, and the second method with limited progress reporting took 6059.5966ms. So it looks like it was indeed a firehose problem.

Thanks Hans, this solves my problem. Could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Of course, the mystery remains why the first method did not cause the same problem. Am I creating some sort of overhead with the Task factory by using the first method, inadvertently lowering the rate at which the UI thread is pummeled? Mysterious.

Comment: My only guess is that reporting progress performs more operations in one case than in the other. Perhaps some bindings cause the whole thing to update more often?

Comment: Hans is correct. Also note svick's comment; `Progress<T>` will do thread marshaling based on what context is active when it is constructed. Additional note: when you call `IProgress<T>.Report`, you should give it an immutable or newly-constructed object; passing an instance that you modify later is incorrect.

Comment: @StephenCleary, Isn't he incurring additional unncessary transferring of work to the UI in the 2nd approach due to using `await` without multiple times (without `ConfigureAwait(false)`) compared with the first approach which would only have to come back to the UI thread once each time through the initial loop?  (I'm directing this to you, due to your expertise in the area).

Comment: Why is that incorrect? I can't find anything about it needing to be immutable/new on MSDN. Any sources?

Comment: @BasDL, you are creating a race condition: by the time the UI thread reads the progress information, you may have changed it.  In the case where you are reporting multiple pieces of information that depend on one another, you could have a ordering occur where you report something inconsistent or incorrect (due to the UI reading some values that have been changed, while others that have not yet been changed).  Why *wouldn't* you want to report immutable values--you never get into trouble that way.

Comment: @BasDL: I've documented it [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html). The only *official* documentation I could find is [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx): "Progress updates are raised asynchronously to avoid delaying the asynchronous operation while event handlers are executing."

Comment: Wasn't aware that it would create a race condition. I figured the built in IProgress implementation would've taken care of that, like it does the thread marshalling. Good to know!

Comment: @MattSmith: The op could (should) add `ConfigureAwait` to their `await`s, but in this case a handful of marshals to the UI thread is being swamped by the progress updates all marshaling. I'm actually more interested in why the WPF binding marshaling is able to handle this but `IProgress` is not; I'm wondering if there's some binding-specific logic that is combining updates behind the scenes (in a firehose scenario).

Comment: @StephenCleary, Ah.. I understand your point now (I think), in the first case, the IProgress<T> is created on the background thread (and so it doesn't do any marshalling).  In the second case, it is created on the main UI thread and does do marshalling.  So, in the first case, the WPF binding has to do all the marshalling work, but in the 2nd case, WPF wouldn't do any marshalling work (it would all be done done by IProgress<T>.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `progress.Report(...)` you are effectively posting a message to the UI thread to update the UI and because you are calling this in a tight loop you are simply flooding your UI thread with report back messages that it needs to process and thus not get time to do anything else (and thus locking up). That is why your `Thread.Sleep(1)` 'hack' is working, because you are giving the UI thread time to catch up.

You need to rethink the way you report back or at least how often you post back. You could use many techniques of buffering the post backs. I would have used a solution from [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You are using await when calling the async method from the event handler. This causes the event handler thread to wait (do nothing) until the async method completes.
From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx .
The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.

Comment: But I'm calling await in the event handler in both cases. In both of those code samples, the event handler thread waits until the async method completes. So why the difference?

Comment: Fair point. The difference then is that Task.Run is actually a synchronous method. It queues the Action to run asynchronously and returns. The await is just waiting for Task.Run to finish, not for the Action to finish.

Comment: Are you sure? Because if I set a breakpoint on the await Task.Run() line and step over it, the next line isn't reached until after parsing has completed, suggesting that it's awaiting the action.

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne That doesn't make much sense to me. The whole point of `Task.Run()` is to execute some code asynchronously. And `await` will wait for the `Action` to finish.

Comment: Exactly - `Task.Run` returns task so natural assumption is that await will cause waiting unti the returned task is completed and then moving to next line - in asynchronous way.

Comment: So, yeah. Task.Run fires off the supplied Action on a new thread and returns the Task for it, which await then waits for to complete. So the await _is_ waiting for the Action to finish like I originally assumed.